# 3SUM (finding all unique triplets in a list that equal 0)

Tags: python, list

I am working on the 3SUM problem (taken from leetcode), which takes a list as input and finds all unique triplets in the lists such that a+b+c=0. I am not really sure what my code is doing wrong, but it currently returns an empty list for this list [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4], so it is not recognizing any triplets that sum to 0. I would appreciate any suggestions or improved code.

Here's my code:

```
result = []
nums.sort()
l = 0
r=len(nums)-1
for i in range(len(nums)-2):
    while (l < r):
        sum = nums[i] + nums[l] + nums[r]
        if (sum < 0):
            l = l + 1
        if (sum > 0):
            r = r - 1
        if (sum == 0): 
            result.append([nums[i],nums[l],nums[r]])
print(result)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple things to note.

1. Don't use `sum` as a variable name because that's a built-in function.
2. Your indexing is a little problematic since you initialize `l = 0` and have `i` begin at `0` as well.
3. Don't rest on your laurels: increment the value of `l` when you find a successful combination. It's really easy to forget this step!

An edited version of your code below.

```
nums = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]
result = []
nums.sort()
r=len(nums)-1
for i in range(len(nums)-2):
    l = i + 1  # we don't want l and i to be the same value.
               # for each value of i, l starts one greater
               # and increments from there.
    while (l < r):
        sum_ = nums[i] + nums[l] + nums[r]
        if (sum_ < 0):
            l = l + 1
        if (sum_ > 0):
            r = r - 1
        if not sum_:  # 0 is False in a boolean context
            result.append([nums[i],nums[l],nums[r]])
            l = l + 1  # increment l when we find a combination that works

>>> result
[[-1, -1, 2], [-1, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 1]]
```

If you wish, you can omit the repeats from the list.

```
unique_lst = []
[unique_lst.append(sublst) for sublst in result if not unique_lst.count(sublst)]

>>> unique_lst
[[-1, -1, 2], [-1, 0, 1]]
```

---

Another approach uses [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). This doesn't require a sorted list.

```
from itertools import combinations

result = []
for lst in itertools.combinations(nums, 3):
    if sum(lst) == 0:
        result.append(lst)
```

---

A nested for loop version. Not a big fan of this approach, but it's basically the brute-force version of the itertools.combinations solution. Since it's the same as approach as above, no sort is needed.

```
result = []
for i in range(0, len(nums)-2):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)-1):
        for k in range(j + 1, len(nums)):
            if not sum([nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]]):  # 0 is False
                result.append([nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]])
```

Comment: It is not an answer, it is a suggestion, so please move it into a comment.

Comment: "I would appreciate any suggestions or improved code." I think this is under the category of improved code.

Comment: @3novak Thank you so much! This looks great and itertools seems useful to keep in mind! I would totally use this code myself, but since I am practicing my coding skills (and may not be allowed to use imports on tests or interviews), I am really looking for code that isn't simplified too much by imports.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the direction, everyone. I really like the `while` approach on the sorted list. My edited response makes some suggestions for modifying that approach to obtain the desired output. Let me know if this raises other questions.

Comment: @3novak Thank you so much for adding to your response. That was super helpful!

Comment: There is a minor mistake in this code. You should bring "r=len(nums)-1" inside for loop.

Comment: Shouldn't "r=len(nums)-1" be inside the for loop and outside/above the while loop?

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment print statement from my solution:

```
class Solution:


    def threeSum(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        # print('Input: {}'.format(nums))
        nums.sort() # inplace sorting, using only indexes
        N, result = len(nums), []
        # print('Sorted Input: {}'.format(nums))
        for i in range(N):

            if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i-1]:
                # print("Duplicate found(when 'i' iterate ) at index: {}, current: {}, prev: {}, so JUMP this iteration------".format(i,nums[i], nums[i-1]))
                continue

            target = nums[i]*-1
            s,e = i+1, N-1
            # print('~'*50)
            # print("Target: {} at index: {} & s: {}  e: {} {}".format(target,i, s, e, '----'*2))

            while s<e: # for each target squeeze in s & e
                if nums[s]+nums[e] == target:
                    result.append([nums[i], nums[s], nums[e]])
                    # print(' {} + {} == {}, with  s: {} < e: {}, Triplet: {},  MOVING --> R'.format(nums[s], nums[e], target,s, e,result))
                    s = s+1

                    while s<e and nums[s] == nums[s-1]: # duplicate
                        # print("Duplicate found(when 's' iterates) at s: {} < e: {}, WILL KEEP MOVING ---> R  (s: {}) == (s-1: {})".format(s, e, nums[s], nums[s - 1]))
                        s = s+1
                elif nums[s] + nums[e] < target:
                    # print(' {} + {} < {}, with s: {} e: {}, MOVING ---> R'.format(nums[s], nums[e], target,s, e))
                    s = s+1

                else:
                    # print(' {} + {} > {}, with s: {} e: {}, MOVING <--- L'.format(nums[s], nums[e], target,s, e))
                    e = e-1

        return result
```

It will help you to understand the algorithm better. Also, this algorithm is 3 times faster than the above available options. It takes ~892.18 ms compared to the above alternative with runs in ~4216.98 ms time. The overhead is because of the additional removal of duplicates logic.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar approach as 3novak, but I added in the case where the number list is less than three integers returning an empty list.

```
class Solution:
def threeSum(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: List[List[int]]
    """        
    # if less than three numbers, don't bother searching
    if len(nums) < 3:
        return []

    # sort nums and use current sum to see if should have larger number or smaller number
    nums = sorted(nums)
    triplets = []
    for i in range(len(nums)-2):    # i point to first number to sum in list
        j = i + 1                   # j points to middle number to sum in list
        k = len(nums) - 1           # k points to last number to sum in list
        while j < k:
            currSum = nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k]
            if currSum == 0:
                tmpList = sorted([nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]])
                if tmpList not in triplets:
                    triplets.append(tmpList)
                j += 1 # go to next number to avoid infinite loop
            # sum too large, so move k to smaller number
            elif currSum > 0:
                k -= 1
            # sum too small so move j to larger number
            elif currSum < 0:
                j += 1
    return triplets
```

I'm doing the same problem at leetcode, but still have a runtime error. This may be able to be done by using a binary search tree-like algorithm to find the third result, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using two pointer approach:

1. First sort the list.
2. Iterate from left to right. Say current position is `i`, set left side position as `i+1`, and set the right end as the end of the list `N-1`.
3. - If the sum is greater than 0, decrease the right end by 1.
   - else if, the sum is less than 0, increase the left end by 1,
   - else, check the uniqueness of the new entry and if it is unique add it to answer list. Continue search for more entry with `leftEnd++, rightEnd--`.

Java Code:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> threeSum(ArrayList<Integer> A) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ans =  new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    Collections.sort(A); // takes O(nlogn)
    if (A.size() < 3) return ans;
    ArrayList<Integer> triplet = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < A.size()-3; i++){ // takes O(n^2)
        if (i > 0 && A.get(i) == A.get(i-1)) continue; // to maintain unique entries
        int r = A.size()-1;
        int l = i+1;
        while (l < r){
            int s = sumOfThree(A, i, l, r);
            if (s == 0){
                if (ans.size() == 0 || !bTripletExists(A, i, l, r, triplet)){
                    triplet = getNewTriplet(A, i, l, r); // to be matched against next triplet
                    ans.add(triplet);
                }
                l++;
                r--;
            }else if (s > 0){
                r--;
            }else {
                l++;
            }
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
public int sumOfThree(ArrayList<Integer> A, int i, int j, int k){
    return A.get(i)+A.get(j)+A.get(k);
}
public ArrayList<Integer> getNewTriplet(ArrayList<Integer> A, int i, int j, int k){
    ArrayList<Integer> newTriplet = new ArrayList<>();
    newTriplet.add(A.get(i));
    newTriplet.add(A.get(j));
    newTriplet.add(A.get(k));
    return newTriplet;
}
public boolean bTripletExists(ArrayList<Integer> A, int i, int j, int k, ArrayList<Integer> triplet){
    if (A.get(i).equals(triplet.get(0)) && 
        A.get(j).equals(triplet.get(1)) &&
        A.get(k).equals(triplet.get(2)))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers given above are great but fails some edge cases on leetcode.
I added a few more checks to pass all the test cases

```
class Solution:
def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:

    # if the list has less than 3 elements
    if len(nums)<3:
        return []

    # if nums is just zeroes return just one zeroes pair
    elif sum([i**2 for i in nums]) == 0:
        return [[0,0,0]]

    nums.sort()

    result = []


    for i in range(len(nums)):

        #duplicate skip it
        if i > 0 and nums[i]== nums[i-1]:
            continue

        # left pointer starts next to current i item
        l = i+1
        r = len(nums)-1

        while l< r:
            summ = nums[l] + nums[r]

            # if we find 2 numbers that sums up to -item
            if summ == -nums[i]:
                result.append([nums[i],nums[l],nums[r]])
                l +=1

                # duplicate skip it
                while l<r and nums[l] == nums[l-1]:
                    l +=1


            # if the sum is smaller than 0 we move left pointer forward
            elif summ + nums[i] < 0:
                l +=1
            # if the sum is bigger than 0 move the right pointer backward   
            else:
                r -=1

    return result
```